# Torrent box, Torrentwatch-x setup install help

Tags: server, apache2, bittorrent, transmission

I'm trying to set up a ubuntu "torrent box" ,

1. samba file sharing
2. transmission remote
3. torrentwatchX - and this is where I am stuck,

-

what I have done so far is

```
sudo apt-get install php-services-json php5-curl php5-cgi
cd ~/Downloads
wget http:// torrentwatch-x.google.code.com...X-0.8.9.tar.gz -O torrentwatch-x.tar.gz
  (-space)
tar xzvf ./torrentwatch-x.tar.gz
sudo mv ./TorrentWatchX-0.8.9/ /var/www/torrentwatch-x/
sudo cp /var/www/torrentwatch-x/php/config.php.dist /var/www/torrentwatch-x/php/config.php
sudo mkdir /etc/torrentwatch
```

-

and this I believe installed torrentwatch? altso Installed Apache2 that I think is required to get this working

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

edited httpd.conf with

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/httpd.conf
```

and wrote /var/www/torrentwatch-x/web

saved

### -

some searching later I:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/conf.d/torrentwatch-x.conf

# Ensure Apache listens on port 9092
Listen 9092

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:9092

<Directory "/var/www/torrentwatch-x">
AllowOverride None
AuthType Basic
AuthName "TorrentWatch-X"
AuthUserFile /etc/torrentwatch/passwords
Require user admin
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:9092>
ServerName hoth.local
DocumentRoot /var/www/torrentwatch-x
</VirtualHost>
```

Some more searching ended with altso:

```
sudo nano /etc/torrentwatch/torrentwatch.config
```

and entered:

```
[Settings]
Episode Only = 0
Combine Feeds = 1
Transmission Login =
Transmission Password =
Transmission Host = localhost
Transmission Port = 9091
Transmission URI = /transmission/rpc
Watch Dir =
Download Dir = /home/torrents/download
Cache Dir = /var/www/torrentwatch-x/rss_cache/
TVDB Dir = /var/www/torrentwatch-x/tvdb_cache/
Save Torrents =
Run Torrentwatch = True
Client = Transmission
Verify Episode = 1
Only Newer = 1
Download Proper =
Default Feed All =
Deep Directories = 0    
Require Episode Info = 1
```

Hope someone can explain what I'm doing wrong/ what more I need to do?

### -

-
**What i need help with is how to insall torrentwatch-x for a noob**
- so now I figured i broke everything so i did a clean ubuntu install to start from scrach, IF i get a assistance :/

Comment: basically https://code.google.com/p/torrentwatch-x/wiki/Installation explained to a "beginner"

Answer (score 0):

I cannot help you with torrentwatchX. However, I did notice this product is no longer supported/being developed due to time constraints of the developer...

Since I don't know what you're trying to accomplish I can only give a possible hint...have you looked at flexget? It doesn't have a GUI (afaik) but works very nice with Transmission, rss-feeds and webpages.

Lots of info can be found on the combination of flexget and Transmission.

Comment: Thanks for responding, (edited post) I realy want torrentwatchx because of it's web inteface and girlfriend friendlyness once set up, I know it's no longer supported but i fugured there must be somebody that know how to get it installed and running. Have looked at flexget aswell but couldnt manage to install that neither (didnt put much efford into it tho because I cant imagine my girlfriend beeing able to operate it which is something i would prefer)